# Preferred/Proper Way to Bind to MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

So I'm building a program that pulls Table and Field names out of a Microsoft Access database and puts them in to two different Listbox items. As a test for my binding I had both boxes setup identically (Just a simple copy/paste because I was getting ahead of myself) and I got the Table names to bind successfully but only using `lbTables.DataContext = this;`(I tried to use `lbTables.SetBinding (ListBox.DataContextProperty, new Binding ("MDBtoCSV.MainWindow"));` but it doesn't work for some reason). The DataContext doesn't seem to inherit from the window above it which from what I've read is what what it's supposed to do.

When I began trying to pin down the DataContext on lbFields in XAML I found an odd problem. if I define and initialize the collection at the same time, globally(as below), `private ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Table>> _listTables = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Label>> ();` both ListBox behave how I would expect them too.

But if I instead initialize the collection in my code and use `lbTables.DataContext = this;`, then only lbTables populates while lbFields remains blank. Is there a preferred method or less fragile method to explicitly defining the DataContext and ItemSource?

Below is my XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbFields" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="10,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240"
             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=appMainWindow, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListTables, Mode=OneWay}">
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

TL;DR: Why would DataContext not inherit from Window? Why doesn't `ListBox.DataContext = this` act the same as the XAML version?

**Edit:**

```
    private ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Table>> _listTables;// = new      ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Table>> ();

    public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Table>> ListTables
    {
        get { return _listTables; }
        private set { _listTables = value;}
    }

public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isChecked;
    private T item;
    private string name;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CheckedListItem () { }

    public CheckedListItem (T item, bool isChecked = false)
    {   this.item = item;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;}

    public T Item
    {   get { return item; }
        set
        {   item = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Item");}
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {   get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {   isChecked = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged ("IsChecked");}
    }

    public class Table
    {   public string name { get; set; }
        private ObservableCollection<string> _listFields = new ObservableCollection<string> (
                    new string[]{"null","null","null","null"});

        public ObservableCollection<string> ListFields { get { return _listFields; } set { _listFields = value; } }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything I'm doing turned out to work just fine, what I was missing was the INotifyPropertyChanged in the MainWindow. I couldn't figure it out before, but then I found [this](http://codingseason.blogspot.in/2013/05/data-binding-xaml-control-to-property.html) which is something that I've been looking for for three months.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you take a look at the [MVVM pattern example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and use that for your WPF and bindings. It makes all of this a *lot* easier.

I would suggest three `ViewModel` classes: `MainWindowViewModel`, `DatabaseTableViewModel` and `DatabaseTableColumnViewModel`. As you might imagine, they are nested in each respective one with some properties of their own like so:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  // Make sure you implement INotifyPropertyChanged and invoke on each property!

  public string Title { get; set; }

  public ObservableCollection<DatabaseTableViewModel> Tables { get; set; }

  public DatabaseTableViewModel SelectedTable { get; set; }
}

class DatabaseTableViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public string TableName { get; set; }

  public ObservableCollection<DatabaseTableColumnViewModel> Columns { get; set; }
}

class DatabaseTableColumnTableViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public string ColumnName { get; set; }
  public string ColumnType { get; set; }

  public DatabaseTableColumnViewModel SelectedColumn { get; set; }
}
```

So your XAML bindings would look something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tables}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTable}">
</ListBox>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedTable.Columns}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTable.SelectedColumn}">
</ListBox>
```

You will have to work a little bit with this to get multiple selection working but that's the general idea with bindings.

You should be setting your `MainWindow.DataContext` to an instance of `MainWindowViewModel`.

Comment: I am basically sticking to MVVM and all of my properties implement INotifyPropertyChanged with the exception of my top most property that hold the list of table names. It's in the main window and I'm not certain how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged other than inheriting it in a class. Also, you're still implicitly assuming the DataContext which is primarily where I believe my issue to be.

Comment: As long as your `ViewModel` objects all implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and your property `set { ... }` blocks invoke the event handler properly, you'll be fine. `ObservableCollection<T>` handles it as well. Your `DataContext` is implied with `Window.DataContext`, hence creating a `MainWindowViewModel`, which should contain all the view models you need to display.

Comment: Except DataContext isn't being implicitly assigned. If I remove `lbTables.DataContext = this;` from my codebehind, I lose the Binding for lbTables while lbFields maintains because its DataContext is hard coded in XAML.

Comment: The question is then why are you needing to set the `DataContext` in your XAML? Is there a particular reason it cannot be set in code? Your `MainWindowViewModel` should be a valid view model for the lifetime of the application (or that particular window).